# Load many small files(avro) from GCS to pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to read many small avro files(~2.8 MB) that are coming from kafka feed per min. into pyspark dataframe using `df_ss7 = spark.read.format('avro').load('gs:<gcs_path>/2022/02/13/*/*/*.avro')`.
The problem here is when I hit enter it takes very long time to load the as there are huge small files. I know this can be dealt with merging the small file in small number of very large files but I have no idea how that can be done in GCS buckets.  I am proving the following parameters to my pyspark shell
`--executor-cores 5  --executor-memory 8g  --driver-memory 8g`

Note - I am using GCP Dataproc cluster to process data using pyspark.

Comment: I think you want to solve it from the source where these small files are created, otherwise you will always read lots of small files.

Comment: @Dagang.. we too facing similar issue while reading a huge number of very tiny CSV files from gcs bucket.. I am too thinking to handle it at source itself.. or do you have another suggestion to handle it at Google cloud. Our file size is too small .. like less than 5 bytes.. and number of incoming files are in thousand..at every 15 minutes frequency

Comment: @vikrantrana, consider ingesting your data to Cloud Pub/Sub, then convert them to bigger files in GCS?

Comment: @Dagang.. whenever files gets ingested they do send a notification to pubsub which then read by cloud function.. are you suggested that merge them into big file within that cloud function and write it back as a big csv file..?

Comment: @vikrantrana, is it possible to ingest the data instead of just notifications into Pub/Sub? Then you can merge multiple items into a big file with Cloud Function and write to GCS. Basically, avoid lots of small files in GCS.